# Move and Leave a link with routing documents

Tags: office-365, records-management, content-organizer

We have the next scenario in Office 365:

1. We have configured Records Management to use Send To Connections with Move and Leave a Link.
2. We have configured a set of rules that expect the user or admin to edit the properties of the document just submitted to match one of these rules. In this step the document is "waiting" in the DropOff library to be completed.
3. When users complete this, the document is redirected to the final library.

So, the problem is that the link left in the original location is pointing to the DropOff Library instead of the final library. Obviously, we need to point the final location. Any ideas will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what we needed is to activate the Documents ID Feature in the site collection:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/activate-and-configure-document-ids-in-a-site-collection-HA102773259.aspx

Remember that after you activate it, you must wait, or force, the timer job (once a day) to run in order to have everything working as expected.